# CSS positioning the search menu correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
I have main outer div.
----Inside that I have outer div
--------and inside that I have inner search menu div
--------and search menu content list div
```

Now I have given fixed position to inner search menu div.
When I scroll outer div part It's position is fixed correctly.

The problem is when I scroll the main div [outer most]then also menu item div is still fixed and it is not scrolling with its outer div.
How can I make it scroll with outer div.

```css
.main{
  width:600px;
  height: 700px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position:relative;
}
.outer{
  width:500px;
  height: 500px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position:relative;
  overflow:scroll;
  
}
.inner{
  width:400px;
  height: 40px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position:fixed;
}
.content{
  margin-top:45px;
  height:600px;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:100px
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner"> 
      </div>
      <div class="content">
      
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `position: sticky` instead of `fixed` and define `top` and `left`:

```css
.inner {
  ...
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

In this case `.main` doesn't need a `position`.

**Working example:**

```css
.main {
  width: 600px;
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.inner {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 45px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You could also use `position: absolute` and define  `top` and `left`:

```css
.inner {
  ...
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

In this case you have to define `position: relative` for `.main` but not for `.outer`.

**Working example:**

```css
.main {
  width: 600px;
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.inner {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 45px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: position:sticky is not supported in all browser. Is there any other alternative.